# Insert query for PostgreSQL

Tags: 7, database

In Drupal 7 with a developed custom module that insert data into a postgreSQL db, I use the following query :

```
$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'move')
  ->query("INSERT INTO clients (client_ref,client_lastname,client_firstname) VALUES('E11366235','DUPOND') RETURNING client_id")
  ->execute();
```

But the returned client_id is always 1.

If I set `INSERT INTO clients (client_ref,client_lastname,client_firstname) VALUES('E11366235','DUPOND') RETURNING client_id` in pgAdmin 3, the returning id is correct.

**In both case data are inserted into database** but Drupal doesn't return the good id.

Any explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to all messages there are two ways to solve the problem :

**1) db_insert**

Using `db_insert()` to insert data and create a specific query for postgreSQL database to get the last id after insert :

```
// Default insert    
(...)->insert("...");

// Call this query to get last id only for pgSQL
(...)->query("SELECT currval('sequence')")->fetchAll();
```

You juste need to replace sequence by the key provided in your postgreSQL database.

You have to call currval right after insert to stay in the same context.

**2) db_query**

Rewriting the entire query with specific synthax for postgreSQL database to get the last id :

```
(...)->query("INSERT INTO {$table} ($fields) VALUES($value) RETURNING $id")->fetchField();
```

**Conclusion**

The first solution seems to be the best to avoid rewriting all `db_insert()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that function you're using is returning the number of rows affected.

You should use ->insert for insert queries, or better yet use drupal's db_insert function:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7

As you can see it uses ->insert and that will hopefully return what you need

Comment: I can't use db_insert because the returning of last insert id doesn't works with PGSQL driver. If I want a custom select query and this is the case I have to use db_query.

Comment: `db_insert()` works at the same way for every database engine; if it doesn't, it is a bug in Drupal core.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `DatabaseConnection_pgsql::query()` has an option for that. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (client_ref,client_lastname,client_firstname) VALUES('E11366235','DUPOND') RETURNING client_id";
$new_id = Database::getConnection('default', 'move')
  ->query($sql, array(), ['return' => Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID]);
```

Comment: If I use this query I get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object" and the page stop render but data are inserted into the database. If I remove ->execute() data is still inserted but $query is set to false. I'm lost.

Comment: Right yeah, my fault - no point changing the return type and then trying to use the original return type. I changed the code, that should work

Comment: After editing, new_id is set but empty :(

Comment: Did you try `->query(...)->execute()->fetchField()`, without the options set?

Comment: ->query()->fecthField() works with my query. I posted a complete solution based on your messages. thanks :)